# How to include a tex file with strange characters in the path

Tags: pdftex, include, paths

I am trying to let pdflatex run and include a file that has several spaces in this. Somhow this fails to work. The code I have down here. The file to include is a seperate tex file.

```
\begin{document}
\include{\path{{"Questions(structurd)/LU9 some functions/question4"}.tex}
\import{}
```

Comment: this will perhaps work in the next latex version, but not now, remove the spaces or try `\input{Questions ...} ` instead of \include.

Comment: Changing include into input has no effect.

Comment: there is no `\path` command defined by default and `\include` you should use the filename _without_ `.tex` in the argument. and what is the intention of `\import{}` which is also not defined by default.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't think that it works currently, see https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/217 (and I tried with quotes).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer well it certainly won't work with `\path` and `{{` and `.tex`  best wouldd be to use `\input{question4}` and just arrange teh directory is in the search path.

Comment: You should be able to use `\input{"Questions(structurd)/LU9 some functions/question4"}` if you really have to have the full path with spaces.

Comment: Spaces or strange characters in a path is ask for problems with or without LaTeX. The smart decision is not try to fix these problems but the source of them, i. e,  rename the path to an `easy/and/sort/relative/path`

Comment: In the end I just decided to remove the spaces from the directory name. Although I am not sure that those where the problem. Thanks for the aid.